# How to skip a column from a table while removing the quote from the column in HIVE using SerDe

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am facing the issue related to **SERDE** quote remove.

I have table table tracker. I have to remove double quote from all column but have to skip on column that contain the json (**Product**). When I load data from CSV file it also remove the quote form the **json data**.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TRACKER
(
SUBSCRIBER STRING,
SERIAL STRING,
PRODUCT STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = ",",
   "quoteChar"     = "\"",
   "escapeChar"    = "\\"
)  STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/tracker'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

**Sample Data in csv**

```
"Raj","400000",{"newData":"d0","olddata":"test1"}
"Rai","400332",{"newData":"data1","olddata":"test2"}
"Ram","444000",{"newData":"New Data","olddata":"test3"}
```

It work fine for first 2 column **SUBSCRIBER** and **SERIAL** but for last field **product** it remove the  quote from json too.

Comment: **(1)** There is a mismatch between `separatorChar` (`,`) and the data sample **(2)** Are the 2 first fields always qualified by `"`?

Comment: Yes...   double quote always we in data..

Comment: You have supplied a non working code.

Comment: @Dudu: Could you please let me know what not working in code... I have tested the same one. it working for me beside i pass , instead of tab.

Comment: Not working as in syntax error. Try it.

Comment: I got your point it related to ' in the location....

Comment: Not only. There is also an issue with `"quoteChar"     = '"'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153631/discussion-between-dinesh-singh-and-dudu-markovitz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**RegexSerDe**

```
create external table if not exists tracker
(
    subscriber  string
   ,serial      string
   ,product     string
)
    row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
    with serdeproperties ('input.regex' = '"(.*?)","(.*?)",(.*)')
    tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1")
;
```

---

```
select * from tracker
;
```

---

```
+--------------------+----------------+---------------------------------------+
| tracker.subscriber | tracker.serial |            tracker.product            |
+--------------------+----------------+---------------------------------------+
| Raj                |         400000 | {"newData":"d0","olddata":"test1"}    |
| Rai                |         400332 | {"newData":"data1","olddata":"test2"} |
+--------------------+----------------+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Dudu, It working fine... I tried previously but missing a small  bit.